# How to do a layer/ shapefile filling of thickness / transparent by value in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, query

I have a shapefile with 500 rows.
My goals is to assign each row a specific value of transparency.

I know I can group these and then manually assign a transparency to these groups, however I want to have them assigned an individual value automatically.

Eg.:

```
name_of_shapefile  value
        A           500  --> 0%
        B           499  --> 1%
        .            .       .
        .            .       .
        .            .       .
        H          -12   --> 99%
```

Currently I have a simply query of `>0 = transparent` and `<0 = not transparent`.

Comment: which field should control transparency ? and how ?

Comment: well that is my question, how do I assign transparency to the value? Obviously I can do it manually or group wise but the "how" is my question.

Comment: You want 500 different transparency values? Why? Who could tell the difference?

Comment: @retrofuture : i didn't mean in which field  will u **store** the transparency .. i meant which field will u derive the transparency **from** ... if u have no rule for applying your transparency ... how can you decide ? Random values ? You obviously want to derive it from your field **'value'** but which logic will you use ?

Comment: starting by the highest value in "value" decreasing to the lowest value in "value". So the 500 in ``value`` is assigned a transparency of 0% the lower the value gets, the more transparent it gets. At least that's my idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the styling of your choose **single symbol**. Under "fill color" click on `data defined override` and then choose **edit** or **assistant**.

if you choose **"edit"** you have to define the **formula** defining your transparency based on your 'value' field.

If you choose **"assistant"** you will be guided and you will have the possibility to define a **transform curve** controling the way the transparency will evolve.

In 'output' you will have to define a **color ramp**.
*(In your case starting from white (depending on your choice) and ending on a fully transparent filling)*

In that case the assistant write the whole formula.